# e.preventDefault doesn't work 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me to find out why this script doesn't work? After hitting the submit button, my form is still being submitted.

Here is the code:

```
submitadd.submit(function(e){     

  var submitadd = jQuery('#submitadd'),
      yearofmanufacturing = jQuery('#yearofmanufacturing'),
      price = jQuery('#price'),
      addtext = jQuery('#addtext');

  if(yearofmanufacturing.val()==''){
    jQuery('#yearofmanufacturing').addClass('bordered2');  
    jQuery('#yearofmanufacturing').removeClass('styled_select'); 
    jQuery("#yearofmanufacturing").attr("placeholder", "Εισάγετε Χρονολία").placeholder();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    alert('yearof......enter in the if');  
  } 
  else {
    alert("yearnotempty?");
  }

  if(price.val()=='') {
    jQuery('#price').addClass('bordered2');  
    jQuery('#price').removeClass('styled_select'); 
    jQuery("#price").attr("placeholder", "Εισάγετε τιμή").placeholder();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    alert('price...enter in the if');
  }

  if(addtext.val()==''){
    jQuery('#addtext').addClass('bordered2');  
    jQuery('#addtext').removeClass('styled_select'); 
    jQuery("#addtext").attr("placeholder", "Εισάγετε περιγραφή αγγελίας").placeholder();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    alert('add text...enter in the if');
  }

  alert('addtext = ' +addtext.val());
});
```

None of the alerts shows when the submit has been clicked. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regard, John

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: `submitadd` what is it?

Comment: Not sure why! but "return false;" instead of preventDefault() should do the trick.

Comment: Not related, but why to cache jQuery objects if you recreate them later anyway?

Comment: no errors in cosole whatsoever....

Comment: submitadd is the name & id of the form

Comment: Also to save space you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bV8zF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save space you could do something like this:

**JQuery**

```
jQuery('#submitadd').submit(function(){     

    var checks = [jQuery('#yearofmanufacturing'), 
                  jQuery('#price'), 
                  jQuery('#addtext')];

    for(var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++){
        var x = checks[i];
        if(x.val() == ''){
            x.addClass('bordered2').removeClass('styled_select'); 
            x.prop("placeholder", "Εισάγετε Χρονολογία");
            console.log('Value for ' + x.prop('id') + ' is empty.');

            return false;
        }
        else {
            console.log('Value for ' + x.prop('id') + ' is not empty.');
        }
    }

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bV8zF/)**

I have rewritten most of the function but it still does the same stuff. I have removed `e.preventDefault();`, instead I am using `return false;`.

If the value is empty. This is also logged to the console (`console.log()`), this is visible when you debug with <kbd>F12</kbd>

Note Aksu's answer too:

> You have specified the **submitadd** variable inside the event. You must move it outside to get event handler fire, otherwise the variable isn't defined, and the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the `submitadd` variable inside the event. You must move it outside to get event handler fire, otherwise the variable isn't defined, and the code doesn't work.

```
var submitadd = jQuery('#submitadd');

// user fill all fields as it should, so form can be submitted
submitadd.submit(function(e){     

   var  yearofmanufacturing = jQuery('#yearofmanufacturing'),
        price = jQuery('#price'),
        addtext = jQuery('#addtext');
   ...
```

Comment: @user2417624 Hmm... i think you should remove all of those `e.preventDefault`s and use **only** `return false;`.

Comment: @Downvouter please explain

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
 submitadd.submit(function(e){
```

to this:

```
 jQuery('#submitadd').submit(function(e){
```

---

In your case the variable `submitadd` is been used before its been declared.

---

or you can declare it before submit:

```
     var submitadd = jQuery('#submitadd')
     submitadd.submit(function(e){
```

Comment: i tried that as well..didn't work. i guess i will rewrite the script from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

**The solution:** Move `var submitadd = jQuery('#submitadd');` out of your function!

---

I would recommend you some things:

- **Use your jQuery variables:**

  Instead of using `yearofmanufacturing`, you write `jQuery('#yearofmanufacturing')` multiple times
- **Naming conventions:**

  I would recommend you to use variable names like `$price` instead of `price`, if you are declaring jQuery objects.
- **Don't write unreachable code:**

  You are trying to call alert() after returning something. This doesn't makes any sense.
- **Don't abuse alert() for debug issues:**

  Use `console.log()`, `console.debug()`, `console.info()` and `console.warn()` for best debugging exceperience.
- **Crossbrowser support:**

  Internet Explorer <= 8 doesn't know `.preventDefault().` Be happy with something like this:
  `(e.preventDefault) ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;`